# Replace identical nested divs within different outer div from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this problem which I am trying to solve after I cloned a div multiple times using javascript. I want to replace the inner div with an empty div having a particular id for each. Assuming I have:

```
<div id="original">
    //some code here
        <div id="problem">
            //some code here
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="location">
//some code here
    <div id="problem">
        //some code here
    </div>
</div>

<div id="rep">
//some code here
    <div id="problem">
        //some code here
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to be able to get the div with id problem in the div location and replace it with something else and same to the div within the div repository.

I tried

`document.getElementById("location")` but that returns the whole content and I cannot replace a particular div within it and if I try `document.getElementById("problem")` I cannot specify which one I need

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Don't ask us to just solve the problem _for you_ - but start by showing us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `querySelector` on a tag to get the first element that match a selector

you can combine it with

- `innerText` / `innerHTML` to modify directly content
- `appendChild` if you have create an html structure in js part

```js
var locationDiv = document.getElementById('location');
var problemDiv = locationDiv.querySelector('#problem');
problemDiv.innerText = 'test';
```

```html
<div id="original">
        <div id="problem">
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="location">
    <div id="problem">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="rep">
    <div id="problem">
    </div>
</div>
```